# Showing all details in a drop down while editing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to edit my shop details. In my editing page, I want to show the previously selected **category_name** as first in drop down.

I am using two variables **$category_list** and **$user_category**
in my $category_list which contains all the shops(with id) available and $user_category contains previously selected shop(with id)

[image]

I want to replace **shops and service** by **newcafe** which is $user-category contains

```
 <select name="category" style="margin-left: 24px; height: 26px; width: 150px;">  
                         <?foreach($category_list->result() as $list)
                         {
                          $selected = "";   
                          foreach($user_category->result() as $list2)
                          {
                          if($list->main_type_name==$list2->main_type_name)
                          $selected = "selected";
                          ?>
                          <option value="<? echo $list->type_id;?>" selected="<?php echo $selected; ?>"<?echo set_select('category',$list->type_id);?>> <? echo $list->main_type_name;?></option>

                          <?}}?>

                        </select>
```

Comment: have you get any error ?

Comment: no .but out come is different

Comment: your question is super confusing. Please make it more clear.Specify what _"shop details"_ is (database results, array, etc...). When you say _" I want to show the previously selected category_name"_ Is that a select dropdown? where is that in your code?

Comment: no.. no "shop details" is not my db. forget it.   and category_name is the select drop down

Comment: for eg: if "newcafe"(category_name) is the selected item from the list while inserting. When iam  trying to edit/change it, drop down list will show the item "newcafe" instead of "shops and service"